# Undefined offset: 0 when try to delete second the element from session array

Tags: php, arrays

i have session variable associated with user
the first time the following code without the second line is execute it works 
on second time it does not giving me undefined offset.

```
unset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$i]);
```

> this line of code solve the problem but my head is not getting around it

```
 $_SESSION["cart_items"] = array_values($_SESSION["cart_items"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unset()` function removes the variable from scope and deletes the data, but it does not re-index the array, so you are left with an array that does not have an index of that number. `array_values()` just re-indexes the array so it is in order.